# Automation Test in CircleCI Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, android-studio, automated-tests, robotium, circleci

Circle Ci Android Test emulator script always fails

**circle.yml** file  used in project.

```
#
#Build configuration for Circle CI
#

general:
artifacts:
    - /home/ubuntu/TestApp/app/build/outputs/apk/

machine:
environment:
    ANDROID_HOME: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
dependencies:
override:
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tools,platform-tools,build-tools-21.1.2,android-21,extra-google-m2repository,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-android-support
     - ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux ./gradlew dependencies


test:
 override:
    - (./gradlew assemble):
        timeout: 360



test:
 override:
# start the emulator
- emulator -avd circleci-android21 -no-audio -no-window:
    background: true
    parallel: true
# wait for it to have booted
- circle-android wait-for-boot
# run tests  against the emulator.
- ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
# copy the build outputs to artifacts
- cp -r /home/ubuntu/TestApp/app/build/outputs $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS
# copy the test results to the test results directory.
- cp -r /home/ubuntu/TestApp/app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/* $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORT
```

**Error Message** shown in **CircleCi**.

```
   com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException
at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:108)
at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:125)
at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:48)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:927)
at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:105)
... 8 more
     Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:513)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:390)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:359)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:566)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.createMultiInstallSession(Device.java:987)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:884)
... 9 more
```

How to solve this issue ? 
It is success when remove emulator test code from circle.yml

Answer (score 5):

Try this in your `circle.yml`:

```
test:
    override:
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=10 ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
        timeout: 360
```

If it doesn't work, add this in your `build.gradle`:

```
com.android.ddmlib.DdmPreferences.setTimeOut(600000)
```

If it's still not working, add `adbOptions` in `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    adbOptions {
        timeOutInMs 600000
    }
}
```

See also [this repo](https://github.com/geekarist/stuff). I had to do all 3 and it works there.

Comment: adding timeout param to connectedandroidtest definitely helped.

Comment: This worked for me. I was testing the download and upload of files and as such needed to extend the default timeout value